# Update NSFetchedResultsController using performBackgroundTask

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an `NSFetchedResultsController` and I am trying to update my data on a background context. For example, here I am trying to delete an object:

```
persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { context in
  let object = context.object(with: restaurant.objectID)
  context.delete(object)
  try? context.save()
}
```

There are 2 things I don't understand:

1. I would have expected this to modify, **but not save** the parent context. However, the parent context is definitely being saved (as verified by manually opening the SQLite file).
2. I would have expected the `NSFetchedResultsController` to update when the background content saves back up to its parent, but this is not happening. Do I need to manually trigger something on the main thread?

Obviously there is something I am not getting. Can anybody explain this?

I know that I have implemented the fetched results controller delegate methods correctly, because if I change my code to directly update the `viewContext`, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 50):

### Explanation

`NSPersistentContainer`'s instance methods `performBackgroundTask(_:)` and `newBackgroundContext()` are poorly documented.

No matter which method you call, in either case the (returned) temporary `NSManagedObjectContext` is set up with `privateQueueConcurrencyType` and is associated with the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` directly and therefore has no `parent`.

See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nspersistentcontainer/1640581-newbackgroundcontext):

> Invoking this method causes the persistent container to create and
>   return a new NSManagedObjectContext with the concurrencyType set to
>   privateQueueConcurrencyType. This new context will be associated with
>   the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator directly and is set to consume
>   NSManagedObjectContextDidSave broadcasts automatically.

... or confirm it yourself:

```
persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { (context) in
    print(context.parent) // nil
    print(context.persistentStoreCoordinator) // Optional(<NSPersistentStoreCoordinator: 0x...>)
}

let context = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
print(context.parent) // nil
print(context.persistentStoreCoordinator) // Optional(<NSPersistentStoreCoordinator: 0x...>)
```

Due to the lack of a `parent`, changes won't get committed to a `parent context` like e.g. the `viewContext` and with the `viewContext` untouched, a connected `NSFetchedResultsController` won’t recognize any changes and therefore doesn’t update or call its `delegate`'s methods. Instead changes will be pushed directly to the `persistent store coordinator` and after that saved to the `persistent store`.

I hope, that I was able to help you and if you need further assistance, I can add, how to get the desired behavior, as described by you, to my answer. *(**Solution** added below)*

### Solution

You achieve the behavior, as described by you, by using two `NSManagedObjectContext`s with a parent-child relationship:

```
// Create new context for asynchronous execution with privateQueueConcurrencyType  
let backgroundContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
// Add your viewContext as parent, therefore changes are pushed to the viewContext, instead of the persistent store coordinator
let viewContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
backgroundContext.parent = viewContext
backgroundContext.perform {
    // Do your work...
    let object = backgroundContext.object(with: restaurant.objectID)
    backgroundContext.delete(object)
    // Propagate changes to the viewContext -> fetched results controller will be notified as a consequence
    try? backgroundContext.save()
    viewContext.performAndWait {
        // Save viewContext on the main queue in order to store changes persistently
        try? viewContext.save()
    }
}
```

However, you can also stick with `performBackgroundTask(_:)` or use `newBackgroundContext()`. But as said before, in this case changes are saved to the persistent store directly and the `viewContext` isn't updated by default. In order to propagate changes *down* to the `viewContext`, which causes `NSFetchedResultsController` to be notified, you have to set `viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` to `true`:

```
// Set automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent to true
persistentContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { context in
    // Do your work...
    let object = context.object(with: restaurant.objectID)
    context.delete(object)
    // Save changes to persistent store, update viewContext and notify fetched results controller
    try? context.save()
}
```

Please note that extensive changes such as adding 10.000 objects at once will likely drive your `NSFetchedResultsController` mad and therefore block the `main queue`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If you could add how I would go about updating data on a background thread and then only updating the fetched results controller when I complete background updates and save up to the parent context (main thread), that would be really appreciated!

Comment: @ganzogo, have you already noticed the added section **solution**? Did it help?

Comment: The automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent solution is what Apple seems to be pushing for. Actually in the Docs, the idea is that automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent is kinda true by default, however seems not to be the case and the boolean is needed.
The docs specify that viewContext is now generated and should be readOnly: "The managed object context associated with the main queue. (read-only), This context is associated directly with the 
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
 and is non-generational by default."

Comment: Sorry to bring up an old thread but this is still relevant. Is there a way to *not* block the main queue, when saving 10,000+ objects on a background context, using `NSPersistentContainer`? I know we can set up the stack manually and have a background context linked to the store coordinator, however, I haven't yet found a way to achieve this using the container. Has anyone managed this?

Comment: @JohnRogers have you found the solution how not to block main queue saving large amounts of data to store coordinator with NSPersistentContainer?
Have you tried to create and set the "parent" private context(with store coordinator) for "viewContext" and set the store coordinator of "viewContext" to nil ?

Answer (score 11):

The view context will not update unless you have set it to automatically merge changes from the parent. **The viewContext is already set as child of any backgroundContext that you receive from the NSPersistentContainer.**

Try adding just this one line:

```
persistentContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
```

Now, the viewContext WILL update after the backgroundContext has been saved and this WILL trigger the NSFetchedResultsController to update.

Comment: I set this line exactly but the view context will not update.  Table view displays data upon restart. Unit test code works as well.  Frustrating, so when I figure out what I am doing wrong I will post.

Comment: @Christopher, make sure to set the tableView datasource before updating.  Also, put breakpoints in other methods on the fetchedresultscontroller to make sure that the controller is seeing the updates..  Also, make sure that the NSFetchedResultsController is properly set up.

Comment: Thanks. Got this working later in the day. Git log shows I was calling "newBackgroundContext()" multiple times and therefore was not saving correctly.

Comment: Veery nice. That one line of code make backgroundContext finally useful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This works me perfectly in  my project.
 In function updateEnglishNewsListener(:), here parameter data is in anyobject and i further convert it into json formate for saving purpose.

Core Data uses thread (or serialized queue) confinement to protect managed objects and managed object contexts (see Core Data Programming Guide). A consequence of this is that a context assumes the default owner is the thread or queue that allocated it—this is determined by the thread that calls its init method. You should not, therefore, initialize a context on one thread then pass it to a different thread.

There are three type 
1. ConfinementConcurrencyType
2. PrivateQueueConcurrencyType
3. MainQueueConcurrencyType

The MainQueueConcurrencyType creates a context associated with the main queue which is perfect for use with NSFetchedResultsController.

In updateEnglishNewsListener(:) function, params data is your input. (data->Data you wants to update.)

```
 private func updateEnglishNewsListener(data: [AnyObject] ){

            //Here is your data

            let privateAsyncMOC_En = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
            // The context is associated with the main queue, and as such is tied into the application’s event loop, but it is otherwise similar to a private queue-based context. You use this queue type for contexts linked to controllers and UI objects that are required to be used only on the main thread.

                   privateAsyncMOC_En.parent = managedObjectContext
                    privateAsyncMOC_En.perform{
                        // The perform(_:) method returns immediately and the context executes the block methods on its own thread. Here it use background thread.

                        let convetedJSonData = self.convertAnyobjectToJSON(anyObject: data as AnyObject)
                        for (_ ,object) in convetedJSonData{
                            self.checkIFNewsIdForEnglishAlreadyExists(newsId: object["news_id"].intValue, completion: { (count) in

                        if count != 0{
                                self.updateDataBaseOfEnglishNews(json: object, newsId: object["news_id"].intValue)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    do {
                        if privateAsyncMOC_En.hasChanges{

                        try privateAsyncMOC_En.save()

                    }
                    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges{

                        try managedObjectContext.save()

                    }

                }catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
    }
```

Checking data is already exist in coredata or not for avoiding the redundance data. Coredata have not primary key concept so we sequently check data already exist in coredata or not. Data is updated if and only if updating data is already exist in coredata. Here checkIFNewsIdForEnglishAlreadyExists(:) function return 0 or value . If it returns 0 then data is not saved in database else saved. I am using completion handle for knowing the new data or old data.

```
    private func checkIFNewsIdForEnglishAlreadyExists(newsId:Int,completion:(_ count:Int)->()){

        let fetchReq:NSFetchRequest<TestEntity> = TestEntity.fetchRequest()
        fetchReq.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "news_id = %d",newsId)
        fetchReq.fetchLimit = 1 // this gives one data at a time for checking coming data to saved data

        do {
            let count = try managedObjectContext.count(for: fetchReq)
            completion(count)

        }catch{
            let error  = error as NSError
            print("\(error)")
            completion(0)
        }


    }
```

Replacing the old data to new one according to requirement.

```
    private func updateDataBaseOfEnglishNews(json: JSON, newsId : Int){

        do {
            let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<TestEntity> = TestEntity.fetchRequest()

            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "news_id = %d",newsId)


            let fetchResults = try  managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>) as? [TestEntity]
            if let fetchResults = fetchResults {

                if fetchResults.count != 0{
                    let newManagedObject = fetchResults[0]
                    newManagedObject.setValue(json["category_name"].stringValue, forKey: "category_name")
                    newManagedObject.setValue(json["description"].stringValue, forKey: "description1")

                    do {
                        if ((newManagedObject.managedObjectContext?.hasChanges) != nil){

                            try newManagedObject.managedObjectContext?.save()

                        }

                    } catch {
                        let saveError = error as NSError
                        print(saveError)
                    }
                }

            }

        } catch {

            let saveError = error as NSError
            print(saveError)
        }
    }
```

Convertion anyobject to JSON for saving purpose in coredata

```
    func convertAnyobjectToJSON(anyObject: AnyObject) -> JSON{
        let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: anyObject, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
        let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
        if let dataFromString = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
            let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
            return json
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Hope it will help you. If any confusion then please ask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So are you saying that it is not possible to make updates using PrivateQueueConcurrency type and this type of context should only be used for reading? If I change to use MainQueueConcurrencyType as you have done, then it all works as expected. However, I was trying to stay off the main thread for as long as possible.

Comment: The private queue concurrency type does all it's work in a background thread. Great for processing or disk io.
The main queue type just does all it's actions on a UIThread. That's neccesary for when you need to do things like bind a NSFetchedResultsController up to it, or any other ui related tasks that need to be interwoven with processing that context's objects. And MainQueueConcurrencyType associated with ui element  and remember i  used perform(_:) function which create the background thread.

Comment: I had already said you "The perform(_:) method returns immediately and the context executes the block methods on its own thread. Here it use background thread"

Comment: The important thing to remember is that when interacting with managed object contexts across multiple threads, all messages sent to the context must be sent via either -performBlock: or performBlockAndWait:.
In a recent project, I had a parent NSManagedObjectContext that backed an NSFetchedResultsController that was created with the NSMainQueueConcurrencyType. ... next comment..

Comment: ...continue...From there I created an NSManagedObjectContext with the NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType and set the context with the NSMainQueueConcurrencyType as the parent. Now my child context could contain discardable edits when adding a new object that would eventually end up in the table view backed by the NSFetchedResultsController which is backed by the parent context.