# Core Data Best Practices - Am I utilizing C.D. Correctly and Efficiently? - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

**How I am Currently Using Core Data:**

My app loads: On this page i create a Managed Object Context, fetch the managed objects, and load / display them.  This is a tableview so I allow deleting.  In order to delete i create a managed object context and delete the managed object and reload the tableview.  This same method is used throughout my app, there are other operations such as updating ect ect.  *The main point is for each action i create a new managed object context.*

My current understanding of Core Data is that a Managed Object Context is sort of like a queue, that fills up with actions.  Where as the Managed Object is the item being modified and placed into the queue for an action to occur.  Using this logic, shouldn't there only be one queue throughout the entire app?

**Main Question:**

Do I need to create a managed object context before every action? or could i create one managed object context say in app delegate did finish launching? and utilize this throughout the entire app?

**Edit:**

For future viewers(and if i understood the answers provided) my code now generally looks like this:

1. I have a class for Core Data, in this one function creates a `ManagedObjectContext`.
2. This function to create a MOC is called in app delegate, which on success returns the MOC, that I then store in a singleton.
3. Throughout my app as I need to make changed to my core data objects, I do the following:

   `if let managedContext = ShareData.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext     { 
   // DO STUFF, update, delete, create ect ect ect
    }`

Edit 2: I may have misinterpreted the "Do not create MOC in App delegate", Currently looking into this and attempting to learn best placement for the creation of MOC. Seems tedious to create one elsewhere if EVERY view you can possibly start the app on requires the MOC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should really only need to create one core data stack throughout the lifetime of the app. (There are exceptions to this but for most apps).

I am currently using [JSQCoreDataKit](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQCoreDataKit) to manage the creation of the stack and saving contexts. It would definitely be worth taking a look at this.

The normal approach to core data is something like...

1. Create the core data stack on launch of the app. Normally accessed through a singleton (NOT IN THE APP DELEGATE).
2. For reading data from core data get the `mainContext` from the core data stack and perform fetches on this `mainContext`.
3. For writing (adding, updating, deleting) data back you can use the `mainContext` but can also get a `backgroundContext` or `childContext` from the core data stack. The perform the updates and `saveContext` inside a `perform` block on the context. (This will merge changes to the main context for you to read).

This should cover most of what you want to do.

Have a look at JSQCoreDataKit. It makes the creation of the managed object context much much simpler.

### Edit to clarify point 1

Putting things into the AppDelegate is a very clunky and lazy way to get at data across the board. The AppDelegate is a singleton so it seems like the perfect place to put it. But then you add more and more and suddenly you have a huge app delegate that drives your entire app.

Using the Single responsibility principle your app delegate should do one thing... be a delegate for you app. It should respond to app state changes etc...

I forgot to add... If you create a second target (say a TVOS target) for your app. It will not use the same AppDelegate. If all your CoreData code (and other code) is inside the AppDelegate then the TVOS app will not be able to access it. Putting it in another class that is accessible to both apps means that both apps can share the code you use for CoreData (et al).

It is very easy to create another file that holds your core data stack and initiate it whenever you first need access to core data. (Not necessarily from the AppDelegate but from the first place you need to make a read/write).

RE placing the core data stack setup in the initial view controller. You could do that. You then have the issue of how do you get to that core data stack from every other view controller in the app. You could either make the initial view controller a singleton (don't do this) or you could pass the stack around.

Both approaches can be done but CoreData is inherently a singleton. There is only one set of data on your phone's disc. So creating a singleton here is not a bad thing.

If you do make a singleton then make it purely a core data stack singleton. I have one called something like `CoreDataStackManager`. All it does is hold the `coreDataStack` property.

Comment: Thank you! Could you clarify step number one and why you SHOULDNT create the core data stack in the app delegate -> then place in singleton?  Would a more appropriate place be in the initial view controllers VDL?

Comment: @Jerland2 edited to add an explanation behind why not to use th AppDelegate :D

Comment: Thank you! VERY Helpful still trying to correctly understand most of what Core Data has to offer and the most efficient way to use it, this helped a lot!

Comment: The statement that you only should create one NSManagedObjectContext is false. NSManagedObjectContext is not thread-safe! You have one main context that you use on the main thread (mostly for reading, and fast small writes), but if you get a lot of data from the backend for instance, you should save it in the background thread, using another NSManagedObjectContext pointing to the same store. https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext

Comment: "If create two managed object contexts (A and B) and then update data in A, you will see the data in B isn't changed." - this is false too.

I understand that you posted an update later, but first line of your answer is a false statement, maybe at least gray it out, if you have a "fix" down in the text.

Comment: @hybridcattt fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I feel compelled to add a minority report to Fogmeister's answer:

1. In the latest SDK, Core Data has provided us with `NSPersistentContainer` which is definitely worth looking into. You don't always need to add a third party dependency to manage Core Data. I usually create set this up in the first visible View Controller and then inject that instance to other view controllers as needed. No need for a singleton; it's much easier to test if you can configure your VC with a persistentContainer.
2. Use the `viewContext` of this persistent store for fetch requests. This runs on the main queue and is suitable for driving the UI.
3. The persistentContainter can be asked for a background context by calling `newBackgroundContext`. You can perform any importing on this queue. When you save this, changes are automatically propagated to the viewContext. Alternatively, use the container's `performBackgroundTask()` method which takes a closure, which will be run on a background queue that is created for you.

**Edited to add**

Here is a very basic example of saving data in a background queue via the `NSPersistentContainer`'s `performBackgroundTask` method. It can be downloaded from Github: https://github.com/Abizern/so-41984004

Comment: Ooh, ok. I'll have a deeper look into that too :) Is this iOS 10 only?

Comment: Note that NSPersistentContainer is only available from iOS 10.0+ . This is not a solution if you want to support iOS V < 10.

Comment: @Abizern just wanted to check :) I will be using this as soon as we can drop iOS9 :D

Comment: I'm afraid you're not right on your last point: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42279670/6793476

Comment: Considering that I have apps in production that do this and work I disagree.

Comment: The returned (or passed in) private `context` is a root context. You can check its `parent` property against `nil`. Following the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext) (last paragraph of _Parent Store_) changes aren't "automatically propagated to the `viewContext`“. Your viewContext could be up to date, though, but its behavior depends on when you fetched data, etc. and I have to admit, that I don’t fully understand its behavior myself.

Comment: @Tobi I've created an example that shows that changes *are* propagated to the Container's viewContext. https://bitbucket.org/abizern/so-41984004

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your effort, I appreciate it! Well I might be pedantic, but you make it work by enabling something which is off by default and that's where the magic happens: `viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true`
I’m not happy about your down vote, because I’m still - and now even more - confident my statement is correct, but most important: Contradictions are clarified ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to create a manger object context each time you want do some operation on database. The best practice is to create a class  containing the MOC and you can centralise in it all possible database operation. this class will be you data access manager

Here an example of what you could look like :

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
enum CommitError: Error {
    case failureToSave(error:Error?)
}
class CoreDataManager: NSObject {
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    override init() {
        // This resource is the same name as your xcdatamodeld contained in your project.
    guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "YOUR_DATABASE_NAME", withExtension:"momd") else {
        fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
    }
    // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL) else {
        fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(modelURL)")
    }
    let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)
    managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc
    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let docURL = urls[urls.endIndex-1]
    /* The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file.
     This code uses a file named "DataModel.sqlite" in the application's documents directory.
     */
    let storeURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("YOUR_DATABASE_NAME.sqlite")
    do {
        let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true, NSSQLitePragmasOption: ["journal_mode": "DELETE"]] as [String : Any]
        try psc.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storeURL, options: options)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)")
    }
}

func commitChanges() throws{
    if self.managedObjectContext.hasChanges{
        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            throw CommitError.failureToSave(error: error)
        }
    }
}

func createObject(_ entityName:String) -> NSManagedObject? {

    let result:NSManagedObject? = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: entityName, into: self.managedObjectContext)
    return result
}

func deleteEntity(_ entity:NSManagedObject){
    self.managedObjectContext.delete(entity)
}
}
```

You can add other function to search or create objects.

Please let me know if this resolve your problem ;)

Comment: Example code creates the stack in the AppDelegate for convenience. Any real world app will not create this here.

Comment: Thank you, this does help me as well in alternative ways to setup my Core Data Stack, currently im using a modified class that is anything but best practices.