# Unable to delete row/coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In my app I have a Table view with values from a mapkit. I can edit the table, delete the row, but when the app starts over, the same deleted rows are still there....How can I fix this? The code for the editing:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

     [_locations removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

     [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

     [tableView reloadData];
 }
```

Any tips? Thank you

Comment: You must **not** call `reloadData` after `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` but you must delete the object also in the Core Data stack and save the context.

Comment: Probably you don't delete your objects from database. Use [NSManagedObjectContext deleteObject:] and then save it.

Comment: All of this I have to implement in the editing table method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Load the data from core data using a `NSFetchedResultsController`.
2. Implement the delegate function to update your views when change occur.
3. When you delete something delete enqueue a block to delete it from core data.  (if you are using `NSPersistentContainer` use `performBackgroundTask:`).
4. **Don't** update your views.  This will happen automatically because of the delegate callback that you implemented in step 2.

Comment: Invoking `save()` on the passed in private `context` of `performBackgroundTask(_:)` won't cause `NSFetchedResultsController` to update: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42279670/6793476

Comment: In your core data setup: `self.persistentContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = YES;`

Comment: Of course, but it’s `NO` by default and consequently `save()` will neither update the `viewContext` nor notify `NSFetchedResultsController`. I merely thought this should be added to your answer.