# IOS 10+ Persistence Store Container set parent context to main context

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nspersistentstore

Following a perfect core data stack, we follow this hierarchy.

[image]

For IOS 10+, Apple introduced `NSPersistentContainer`.
In which Apple described the way for getting background context by

```
let backgroundcontext = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
```

And the Main Context is described as

```
let maincontext = persistentContainer.viewContext
```

And `NSPersistentContainer` is associated with this `backgroundcontext`. So any save operation on this context will be passed on to `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

My Question is how to follow this hierarchy mentioned in the image? No tutorial has mentioned changing the parent context for `maincontext`.

Means saving in `backgroundcontext` and `maincontext` will do I/O operation to `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`?

The perfect CoreData Stack should be like that

***Saving in maincontext will get saved in backgroundcontext. And Save operation on backgroundcontext will save data to NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.***

How this should be achieved?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892147/update-nsfetchedresultscontroller-using-performbackgroundtask